# Handling multiple types of connections by a server

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I'm developing a server that allows clients to communicate to a hardware simulation, simulating the underlying connection type. When a client initially connects, the server doesn't know what type of connection to simulate. The client's first packet to the server requests the connection to be of a specific type.

How do servers usually handle connections of different types? I've only ever worked on servers where all connections were the same. I started off implementing three unrelated connection classes - an "unknown connection" class, and two others that simulate the other connection types. When the connection type is determined, the unknown connection creates a connection of the appropriate type, registers the connection with a registry, then passes off the socket handle to the new connection.

Is it more common to have a single connection implementing a state machine, each type represented by a state, which in turn contains another state machine to handle the type-specific state? Are there alternative designs worth considering?

**[Update]**
After starting to implement the suggestion made by codenheim, I realized some design factors that make it a less-than-attractive solution for my specific problem. The biggest issue is that, regardless of connection type, I need to wait for a connection to receive a hardware address before anything can be done with the connection. If I use the listen port to determine connection type, I have to repeat the logic for receiving the hardware address in each connection type. I also have to keep a list of connections in this state for each connection type, even though they are all essentially doing the same thing - waiting for a hardware address.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional practice is to separate each protocol on a unique port. This allows you to write modular protocol handlers that each bind to their own port and even register the ports by protocol name if the OS supports that (such as inetd and /etc/services on UNIX).

In your current design, your server has to handle the initial "knock" packet. If you don't like that particular aspect (and can't use distinct ports), you may consider using the approach of knockd (port knocking). knockd handles the initial knock sequence before opening the port up (with filter rules, but you could proxy the connection instead). The services being protected know nothing about it. But all this does is move the handshake from one server to another. With unique ports, you can do away with the handshake.

Comment: A unique port for each connection type should work fine in my situation, prevent the need to pass off the socket (which I thought was pretty ugly anyways), and will require only minor changes to my configuration files. I will still need an initial packet from the client to send connection parameters to the server, but it solves the problem of knowing the connection type and simplifies the design. I'm not exactly sure how I'd go about the port knocking technique though.

Comment: I ran into some issues while implementing this, and have update my post accordingly.

Comment: The solution to your update is to keep all of the handlers in the same code base. I've used this in a GPS server that supported various device protocols and each protocol handler was a class with its own port, listening, and running on its own thread. But the common code was shared.